# JSON парсер для Java

Tags: java, json, парсер

Имею JSON данные, использую eclipse + java

1. какие существуют инструменты (библиотеки) для парсинга JSON данных?
2. как лучше: все вакансии (в JSON формате) закинуть в один файл и затем парсить один файл или каждую вакансию закинуть в отдельный файл а затем парсить каждый файл отдельно?

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/java-json-library-comparison/

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/280782/

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: А зачем вообще закидывать JSON в файлы? Парсите сразу как только получили.

Comment: Хм, а так можно? попробую

Comment: Вам нужен Retrofit - при правильной настройке вы просто вызываете метод и он качает JSON, парсит его в модель-класс и возвращает ответ